# Does Miles Morales' invisibility power come with limits or tradeoffs?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

I have not read the Miles Morales Spider-Man books. I just watched *Into the Spider-Verse*.

Does the invisibility power come with limits or tradeoffs? It seems like a plot-breaker if he could just stay invisible all the time. In the movie, he's still learning to control his powers. But I'd imagine if he could control it, he could just stay invisible all the time when fighting villains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only blending camouflage in the comics, not full invisibility, so it doesn't tend to hold up as well mid-combat, or with observers from multiple angles.